# How to insert HTML into datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables to display a table on my site. Each element in the table contains some HTML, like buttons, colored text, etc. How can I update the table rows using the AddRow function such that the HTML gets displayed accurately, i.e., the text is displayed correctly, and the buttons are clickable?

Comment: based on your requirement, i guess you just need to place the elements within table row by constructing each element within your `addRow()` module

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: What did you try? according to what you said, it's not a big deal. Datatable can do it well.